# Is there a way to convert an integer to a string?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Vehicles
{

public:

int wh;

void wheels () {
cout << "Enter number of wheels: ";

cin >> wh;

if (wh == 2) {
    cout << "You chose a Motorcycle!\n";
} else if (wh == 3) {
    cout << "You chose a Tricycle!\n";
} else if (wh == 4) {
    cout << "You chose a Car!\n";
}
} 
} ; //type of vehicle

int main () {
Vehicles number;
number.wheels();
int wheels = number.wh;

cout << "Your vehicle is a " << number.wh; //I would like to say it as a car or the other two vehicle, but the code was an integer
}
```

Is there a way to convert the integer and make it a string? I would like to say it as a car or the other two vehicle mentioned above in the code, but I don't know which code I should use.

Comment: read about `string::to_string`

Comment: You do not really want to convert an integer to a string, what you want is to select one of several strings, based on an integer.

Comment: String to Integer: std::stoi, Integer to string: to_string

Comment: The function `wheels()` is doing two things: it's getting a value, and it's interpreting that value. If you want to be able to interpret the value separately, all you have to do is pull that code from `wheels()` and put it into a new function. This kind of transformation is called "refactoring". Since there's already an answer that's been accepted, I'm not going to write an answer that illustrates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can represent as a vehicle type by selecting a suitable string via the integer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

vector<string> types {"Weird vehicle", "monocyle", "bike", "tricycle", "car"};

class Vehicles
{
public:
    int wh;

    void wheels ()
    {
        cout << "Enter number of wheels: ";
        cin >> wh;
    } 
} ; //type of vehicle

int main () {
    Vehicles number;
    number.wheels();
    int wheels = number.wh;

    cout << "\nYour vehicle is a " << types[number.wh]; 
}
```

You could move that lookup vector and make it a static part of the class and then add a static representation method, for outputing the wheel number attribute as string.

Comment: basically OP was already mapping `2` to the string `"You chose a Motorcycle!\n"` and `3` to `"You chose a Tricycle!\n"`. I'd make that `if` also use the `types` to simplify the code a bit

Comment: @largest_prime_is_463035818 Thanks for nudging me into cleaning up. I like it better now myself. Hope it also is better for you now.

Answer (score 2):

when you say convert int to string we think about
converting `foo = 13` into `foo = "13"`

but what you need is something else.

define your own method in the Vehicle class

```
std::string Vehicles::getVehicleType ()
{
    if (wh == 2) {
        return "Motorcycle";
    } else if (wh == 3) {
        return "Tricycle";
    } else if (wh == 4) {
        return "You chose a Car!\n";
    }
}
```

and in main

```
int main ()
{
    ...
    cout << "Your vehicle is a " << number.getVehicleType();
}
```